# Running storm locally NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm

I am trying to run storm locally and I have the following pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>EVB</groupId>
    <artifactId>firstProject</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>EBS</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                             <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>App</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

mvn clean package works and it deliveres me a jar file. i checked the manifest file inside the jar and it seems fine from the classpath point of view.

when trying to run the jar with java -jar i get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/storm/topology/IRichSpout
```

any ideas on how should i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

As far I know, `IRichSpout` is part of the `storm-client`-Package.
So just add in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
    <artifactId>storm-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```